# Backbone Marionette - throws error on call of Layout extend

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In my app, I am using `Marionette` the extension of `Backbone`. I am getting as a first error as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

And I am trying to append my header, and content with footer to wrapper element... using this script:

But Not working at all...

What would be the correct way to do this?

template:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script id="layout-template" type="text/template">   
    <section>     
        <navigation id="menu">ABC</navigation>     
        <article id="content">123</article>   
    </section> 
</script>
```

script:

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({ 
    template: "#layout-template",
    regions: { 
        menu: "#menu", 
        content: "#content"
    } 

});

var layout = new AppLayout(); 
$('#wrapper').html(layout.render().el);
```

Here is the [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hL2fqyyj/1/)

Any one help me to render all my elements to wrapper please?

Comment: Marionette changed `Layout` to `LayoutView` in the `2.0` release, so it should be `Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend`

Answer (score 2):

You should use this way:

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({ 
    template: "#layout-template",
    regions: { 
        menu: "#menu", 
        content: "#content"
    } 

});
```

As  Kyle Needham said, change `Layout` for `LayoutView`.